# Ubuntu and Windows behave differently when decoding an action parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Steps to reproduce:

---

GET request (via Postman or similar):

```
http://localhost:56024/api/controllername/https%3A%2F%2Fsomething.com
```

Where `url = encodeURIComponent('http://something.com')`. This results in `url = http%3A%2F%2Fsomething.com`.

That is to say, the GET request is decomposed into:

```
'http://localhost:56024/api/controllername/' + encodedParameter
```

ASP.NET Core API Controller:

```
[Route("api/controllername")]
public class ControllernameController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("{*url}")]
    public IActionResult MyAction(string url)
    {
        // Windows (test): url == "http:/something.com" <= Wrong
        // Ubuntu (prod): url == "http%3A%2F%2Fsomething.com" <= OK
    }   
}
```

---

Projectname.csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
    <TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>
    <TypeScriptToolsVersion>Latest</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  ...     

</Project>
```

---

How can I fix the behavior on Windows?

I am using Visual Studio Community 2017 Version 15.5.7 on Windows 10.

Comment: How is your project set up? Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)...

Comment: Your example doesn't jive with itself, even. Top example you have two // and bottom just one. This indicates that you haven't actually ran the code. Also, you shouldn't be encoding the hostname portion of the URI, just the parameter portion. You most likely are looking for a different function

Comment: @JoePhillips I don't understand what are the inconsistencies you say you see in my code. And `url` is just a parameter in my action, not the full request. That is to say: I call it via Postman with a GET request to `http://localhost:56024/api/controllername/https%3A%2F%2Fsomething.com`. Everything works fine in my ubuntu server, but on Windows I don't receive `url = https%3A%2F%2Fsomething.com` as it should.

Comment: @fredrik I have modified the original post to provide a better Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. I agree that mentioning javascript at the beginning of the post was a bit confusing.

Comment: @XavierPeña it's still not an MCVE, there's a tonne of stuff missing for me to be able to reproduce - like the actuall client side call, and the setup and configure on server side.

Comment: @fredrik Come on... he's not going to install visual studio for you. He's provided plenty to reproduce it

Comment: @fredrik Thanks for your answer. The client side call is explained at the top of the post => GET request: `http://localhost:56024/api/controllername/https%3A%2F%2Fsomething.com`. It is late now, but tomorrow I'll try to set up a minimal project on github to reproduce the issue, and link it here.

Comment: @JoePhillips No, he didn't. There are plenty of configurations items left out that can affect how the components work. the csproj file and a few lines of codes are hardly enough to reproduce properly... For example, the entire startup.cs file is an unknown. Also, it's unknown HOW the call to the server is made, from which browser and platform.  At least the JS code making the call is of upmost importance.